# Connect to ElasticSearch .net

Tags: asp.net, .net, elasticsearch, kibana

I am trying to connect at elasticsearch server using .net and i can’t pass login step.
I use system.web, system.net, newtonsoft.json. I don’t have internet connection to download nest or elasticsearch.net.
I tried to acces the url using web.client but i had 401 error so i used this

```
string username = "your";
string password = "password";
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http:Link:elasticPort");
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream(), Encoding.ASCII);
writer.Write("nick=" + username + "&password=" + password);
}

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

But i have this error:

> System.Net.ProtocolViolationException:Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type

The main target is to connect to elasticSearch to get access at indexes.
Is there a better solution to connect?

Comment: I prefer to use NEST for all kinds of Elastic related operations https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/introduction.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, a webclient object, with credentials property like:

Webclient client = new webclient();
Client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(“user”,”passwd”);